# How can we retrieve state of UIView with its all subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am working on a PhotoEditing application where user can choose any image from photo gallery or from there social media account, user can add text & stickers in that image. User can zoom, rotate any added subview.

I want to save the image with all subviews (like add text, stickers etc) & want to retrieve after save in the same state as it was means user can get the complete image with all subviews with their exact position, size & can do changes in that again.

Anybody know how can i achieve this feature ? Please suggest me what should i do to achieve this feature.

Similar question which is also waiting for response is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375935/how-to-preserve-state-of-a-uiview-with-subviews-in-ios

Comment: Check this link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like to do is quite complicated.

The way I would suggest (or imagine myself) doing would be to create a custom format (most likely a combination of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) which describes everything you've added onto the image.

For example, something like:

```
Photo name = "aPhoto"
Added items = 
    {
      item = text
      value = "Some added text"
      positionX = 160
      positionY = 150
      rotation = 30
    }
    {
      item = sticker
      value = heart
      positionX = 200
      positionY = 250
      rotation = -60
    }
```

Save that dictionary to a `plist` for example, and when the user opens the image, you can recreate the whole picture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will give a try to your suggestion.

Comment: See you in a few days :)